# Передать элемент из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript

```
function edit(td) {
td.innerHTML="<div class='cancel_save_field' onclick=\"cancel('"+td+"')\"></div>"
}
function cancel(td) {
alert(td); // Object HTMLTableCellElement
alert(td.parentNode); //undefined
td.style.backgroundColor='black'// Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined 
}
```

Хочу передать ссылку на ячейку из одной функции в другую. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функцию cancel нужно выполнить в контексте функции edit т. е. вот так [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_K88/EjnDb/)